# RISC - V "Attempting to access uninitialized memory between the stack and heap."

Tags: assembly, riscv

I am a student studying Risc V. I'm trying to implement a Matmul function that contains Dot product function, but I get an error "Attempting to access uninitialized memory between the stack and heap."
(Dot product function is fully operational)
I don't even know where this error comes from. Help me, please.
Please let me know if you need any more information. I didn't put in dot function because I was worried that the contents of the post might get longer.

test_matmul.s

```
.import ../matmul3.s
.import ../utils.s
.import ../dot.s

# static values for testing
.data
m0: .word 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
m1: .word 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
d: .word 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 # allocate static space for output

.text
main:
# Load addresses of input matrices (which are in static memory), and 
set their dimensions

la s0 m0
addi s1 x0 3
addi s2 x0 3
la s3 m1
addi s4 x0 3
addi s5 x0 3
la s6 d

#la s7 arr0
#la s8 arr1

# Call matrix multiply, m0 * m1

mv a0 s0
mv a1 s1
mv a2 s2
mv a3 s3
mv a4 s4
mv a5 s5
mv a6 s6
jal ra matmul

# Print the output (use print_int_array in utils

mv a0 a6
addi a1, x0, 3
addi a2, x0, 3
jal print_int_array

#mv a1 a2
#mv a0 a6
#mv a2 a5
#jal ra print_int_array


# Exit the program
jal exit



.globl matmul

.text
# function: Matrix Multiplication of 2 integer matrices
#   d = matmul(m0, m1)
#   If the dimensions don't match, exit with exit code 2
# Arguments:
#   a0 is the pointer to the start of m0 / result of dot
#   a1 is the # of rows (height) of m0
#   a2 is the # of columns (width) of m0, length
#   a3 is the pointer to the start of m1
#   a4 is the # of rows (height) of m1
#   a5 is the # of columns (width) of m1
#   a6 is the pointer to the the start of d
# dot :
#   a0 is the pointer to the start of v0 (vector)
#   a1 is the pointer to the start of v1 
#   a2 is the length of the vectors 
#   a3 is the stride of v0 
#   a4 is the stride of v1
# dot Returns:
#   a0 is the dot product of v0 and v1
# matmul Returns:
#   None, sets d = matmul(m0, m1)*
```

matmul.s

```
matmul:

# Error if mismatched dimensions
bne a2, a4, mismatched_dimensions

li s0 0     #index of mat 1 rows i
li s3 0     #index of mat 2 row k
li s2 0     # length * 4 * i 
li s4 0     # a0 update
li s5 0     # 4 * k
li s6 0     # a3 update

addi sp, sp, -20
sw ra, 0(sp)

outer_loop_start:

mul s2 s0 a2 # [i][[], length * i
slli s2, s2, 2 # length * 4 * i 
add s4, a0, s2 # a0 + length * 4 * i 

inner_loop_start:

beq a2, s3, inner_loop_end
slli s5, s3, 2 # 4 * k
add s6, a3, s5 # a3 + 4 * k

sw a0, 4(sp)
sw a1, 8(sp)
#sw a2, 4(sp)
sw a3, 12(sp)
sw a4, 16(sp)

mv a0, s4
mv a1, s6
addi a3, x0, 1
add a4, x0, a2

jal ra dot 

sw a0 0(a6)

lw a0, 4(sp)
lw a1, 8(sp)
#lw a2, 4(sp)
lw a3, 12(sp)
lw a4, 16(sp)

addi a6, a6, 4
addi s3, s3, 1 # k++

j inner_loop_start

inner_loop_end:

mv s3, x0 # k = 0
addi s0 s0 1 # i ++
bne s0 a1 outer_loop_start

outer_loop_end:

mul s0 a1 a5
slli s0 s0 2
li s1 -1
mul s0 s0 s1
add a6 a6 s0
lw ra, 0(sp)
addi sp, sp, 20

ret

mismatched_dimensions:

li a1 2
jal exit2
```

dot.s

```
.globl dot

.text
# =======================================================
# FUNCTION: Dot product of 2 int vectors
# Arguments:
#   a0 is the pointer to the start of v0
#   a1 is the pointer to the start of v1
#   a2 is the length of the vectors 반복 횟수 
#   a3 is the stride of v0 
#   a4 is the stride of v1
# Returns:
#   a0 is the dot product of v0 and v1
# =======================================================
dot:

# Prologue
lw t0, 0(a0)
lw t1, 0(a1)
addi a2, a2, -1 #length - compare with index
mul t5, t0,t1
mv t6, x0 #i
mv t5, x0 #result

loop_start:

slli t2, t6, 2 # 4i
mul t0, t2, a3 #4i*S0
mul t1, t2, a4 #4i*S1
add t4, a0, t0# V0 + 4i*S0
add a6, a1, t1 # V1+ 4i*S1
lw t0, 0(t4)
lw t1, 0(a6)
mul a5, t0, t1
add t5, t5, a5
beq a2, t6, loop_end
addi t6, t6, 1


j loop_start



loop_end:

mv a0, t5

# Epilogue


ret
```

When using RARS, how import other code files to the main code?

[image]

Comment: On which instruction?  The debugger in RARS should tell you.  (I assume that's what this is?)  Also, it's poor style to omit the commas between operands for some of your instructions.  Use commas consistently, and indent your instructions one level to the right of your labels.

Comment: Thank you for your advice on how to write the code. Is the RARS you mentioned a debugger exclusively for RiscV?
I execute the code using the test_matmul.s given by professor. If you type java-jar venus.jar test_files/test_matmul.s in the terminal window, test_matmul.s will run matmul funtion and dot funtion. It doesn't tell me what instruction caused the error.

I guess the algorithm involved in the loop is causing the problem, but I'm not really sure exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Far too many students being forced to code without a debugger leads to far too many students who don't know how to use one.  And since this is assembler, I don't think you can even do "printf" debugging here.  Basically then, every single memory access you make in your code is now suspect and must be closely examined.

Comment: If I use RARS, can I know where the problem occurred?

Comment: Venus supports debugging.  https://github.com/kvakil/venus mentions "Single-step debugging with undo feature" as a feature.  So fire up its GUI and run the program.  https://github.com/kvakil/venus/wiki/Simulator.    (RARS is an IDE / simulator for RISC-V like Venus, but different.  Since you're already using Venus, you should continue using that, but use its debugging capabilities to avoid wasting your time when it could just show you which instruction did something bad.)

Comment: Are you saying that RARS is better at finding mistakes than Venus?

Comment: You can include files in RARS like `.include "matmul.s"`. This is documented at https://github.com/TheThirdOne/rars/wiki/Assembler-Directives.

RARS won't output an error for this program though because it allows reading uninitialized memory. I would recommend adding `ebreak` instructions to various points in the code and running until venus errors which should narrow down where the error is.